# Firefox 57.0.4 and NoScript: How do I get the right-click menu back?

Tags: firefox, noscript

Just updated Firefox to 57.0.4 to patch the recent Meltdown and Spectre exploits. The NoScript UI now has a button on the toolbar instead of the traditional right-click context menu. How do I get the old context menu back?

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm if there are any plans to put the right-click menu back in official Firefox moving forward?

Comment: Just checked for NoScript updates and the context menu option is technically back but it only opens the toolbar button window. That wasn't exactly what I asked for...